# How to generate a monthly report (between 2 dates) with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently working on a web application (Node js) that has bar graphs indicating the number of sales done per month.

I have a table that has *id*, *job_name*, *date_completed*, and *status* columns (the first two columns seem to be irrelevant for this question).

I want to be able to query the number of completed jobs per month between two values (e.g. 2020-01-01 [January 2020] to 2020-12-01 [Dec. 2020]), with the condition that it will only count those with *status* value '1' (1 = complete, 0 = ongoing) with the query producing this table:

----------+-----------------------

Months  | Jobs Completed

Jan 2020 | 3

Feb 2020 | 1

Mar 2020 | 5

...

Dec 2020 | 3

---------+-------------------------

I'll be using the data to turn it into json using node.js / pg-node.

I've looked at generate_series and row_to_json / json_agg but stumped at how to make this query work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(tbl.date_completed) as month,
    COUNT(tbl.staus) as jobs
FROM yourTable tbl
WHERE
    tbl.date_completed BETWEEN CAST ('2020-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST ('2020-12-01' AS DATE)
    AND
    status = 1
GROUP BY MONTH(tbl.date_completed)
```

this should work, but not tested

Comment: There is no `MONTH()` function in postgres.

Comment: maybe trying `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM tbl.date_completed)` works?

Comment: Hi nodir.dev, it worked thank you! I used your query + the suggested extract(Month ...) function and it returned the data, although if I may ask another help, I would like to also show the months in-between the two dates even if it has 0 return value, e.g.
(range Jan 2020 - Dec 2020)
----
(month | jobs)
(1 | 0)
(2 | 7)
(3 | 0)
..
(12 | 3)

Thank you!

Comment: I think changing `COUNT` to `SUM` and removing `AND status=1` would do exactly what you want

Comment: @nodir.dev it didn't work sadly, it still only generates the months that have value while ignores those that do not have any. I've made progress earlier with some problems such as the other months copying the highest value instead of showing their own and the order of months.

I made a db fiddle, I hope you can help me, thank you!

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gH7C7R6udMucjSATpw8Erh/0